# The method sum(int, int, int, int) is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java, methods

> Create a method called average that calculates the average of the
>   numbers passed as parameters. The previously created method sum must
>   be used inside this method!
>
> Define the method in the following template:
>
> ```
> public static int sum(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
>     // you can copy your implementation of the method sum here
> }
>
> public static double average(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
>     // write your code here
>     // calculate the sum of the elements by calling the method sum
> }
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     double result = average(4, 3, 6, 1);
>     System.out.println("Average: " + result);
> }
> ```

I'm struggling with putting a sum() method within my average() method. I can't figure out how to get it to work because I keep getting this error in eclipse:

```
The method sum(int, int, int, int) in the type Test066 is not applicable for the arguments (int)
    at Test066.average(Test066.java:12)
    at Test066.main(Test066.java:5)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Test066 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result = average(4, 3, 6, 1);
        System.out.println("Average: " + result);
    }

    public static int sum(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
        return number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;
    }

    public static double average(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
        int avg = sum(number1 + number2 + number3 + number4);
    }
}
```

I understand it has something to do with me defining the average method as a double type, but I've tried changing them out to double and calling my variable "int avg = ..." as "double avg = ..." but I'm still getting the same error. I'm not sure how to lump it in since I'm used to calling it in my main method, not in a separate method.

Comment: You should write down the formula for an average and look carefully at it.  How would you tell someone to take an average?

Comment: You need to cast the sum into a double and then return the double divided by 4 inside the average method.

Comment: @markspace What I would do normally would be: 

int sum = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;
int avg = sum / 4;

Comment: @mightymorphinParkRanger The error you're seeing is because you're doing this: `sum(number1 + number2 + number3 + number4)`, which you intend to do this: `sum(number1, number2, number3, number4)`.

Comment: the `sum` method needs 4 arguments (type `int`), your code is passing just one - the result of summing all numbers! `int avg = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4)` the sum is done inside the method. Next step would be calculating the average (as `double`, not `int` (unless that is wanted))

Comment: Have you learned about arrays yet? Have you learned about varargs methods yet? I believe *(I'm guessing of course)* that your method is wrong and should have taken the numbers is an array or as varargs.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> The method sum(int, int, int, int) in the type Test066 is not applicable for the arguments (int)
>   at Test066.average(Test066.java:12)
>   at Test066.main(Test066.java:5)
> ```

The following line in your code is the culprit:

```
int avg = sum(number1 + number2 + number3 + number4);
```

Your `sum` method declaration indicates that it accepts 4 integers as arguments. But when you call it, you are passing only 1 argument - `number1 + number2 + number3 + number4` is one integer, not 4.

Correct it to

```
int avg = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4);
```

With this your code will start compiling. But it might not give you the correct result. As others have indicated, you need to divide the sum with number of operands to get an average.

```
int avg = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4) / 4;
```

Also, the average will be a floating  point number. So you would want to do a floating point division and store it in a `double` data type to avoid truncation.

```
double avg = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4) / 4.0;
return avg;
```

Answer (score 0):

`int avg = sum(number1 + number2 + number3 + number4);`

`number1 + number2 + number3 + number4` converts those 4 numbers into one, so you are trying to call `sum(int)` which doesn't exist.

Try `int avg = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jordan. I was still referring to the sum() method as though I were still in that method. I should've just replaced the plus signs with commas. So it should look like this:

```
public class Test066 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result = average(4, 3, 6, 1);
        System.out.println("Average: " + result);
    }
    public static int sum(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
        return number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;
    }
    public static double average(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
        double avg = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4) / 4;
        return avg;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. If the correct value is `x` (positive/negative), this will give the `Math.floor(x)/Math.ceil(x)`, not `x`.

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue:

```
sum(number1 + number2 + number3 + number4)
```

Your method is

```
public static int sum(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4)
```

That takes 4 arguments. By doing `number1 + number2 + number3 + number4` you are passing one argument, since you are adding all the numbers together.

What you want instead is:

```
int sum = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4);
```

And, of course, you still need to calculate the average correctly after getting the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add:

```
double avg = (double)sum(number1,number2,number3,number4)/4;
```